# Couldn't fetch other IPs and Ports Gamedig discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js, gamedig

I am trying to make all servers information in one embed, but the problem is that the bot fetches all the IPs and ports, giving correct server information but did not give right IPs and ports. It means the bot will give only one server IP and ports from all the servers!

Here is **Updatecmd.js**

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const Gamedig = require("gamedig")

const servers = new Discord.Collection()

function getServerInfo() {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve("../serverinfo.json")] // ensure new IPs were not added

    let serverInfo = require("../serverinfo.json")
    // console.log(serverInfo.length)

    let ip = ""
    let port = 0


    for (let i = 0; i < serverInfo.length; i++) {

        if (i & 1) {
            port = serverInfo[i]
            // console.log(`**port** ` + port)
        } else {
            ip = serverInfo[i]
            // console.log(`**ip** ` + ip)
        }

        

        // query each IP in the file.
        Gamedig.query({
            type: "cs16",
            host: ip,
            port: port,
            socketTimeout: 5000,
            udpTimeout: 10000
        }).then((state) => {
            let serverName  = state.name
            let map         = state.map
            let players     = state.players.length
            let maxPlayers  = state.maxplayers
            
            servers.set(serverName, [serverName, ip, port, map, players, maxPlayers])
            //console.log(servers)
        }).catch((error) => {
            
        })
    }

    return servers
}

getServerInfo()

module.exports = {
    name: 'updatecmd',
    description: 'updatebot test.',
    aliases: ['memes', 'dm', 'dank'],
    usage: `meme`,
    category: 'Fun',
    execute(client, message, args) {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.client.user.username)
            .setFooter("test")
            .setColor("#3498DB")
            .setDescription("zzz")
        
            getServerInfo().forEach((val, key, map) => {
                //console.log(map.size)
    
                let info = servers.get(key)
                //console.log(info)

                embed.addField(`${info[0]}`, true)
                embed.addField("Players:", `${info[5]}/${info[6]}`, true)
                embed.addField("Map:", `${info[4]}`, true) 
                embed.addField("Connect", `${info[1]}:${info[2]}`)      
            })
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

Here is **serverinfo.json**

```
[
    "serverip", port,
    "serverIP",port
]
```

Comment: So what exactly does the embed end up like? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Your JSON file is not formatted correctly. I suggest you read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) on how to correctly use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

For the serverinfo, yes it's not formatted correctly

> [
> "serverip": "port",
> "serverIP": "port"
> ]

Comment: only promblem of giving ips! means the bot only giving one ip! need help